Achieving Real-time Performance and Thread Synchronization in Cooperative Scheduler
I am currently developing with a cooperative scheduler (e.g., uC/OS-II) and have encountered a problem. The specific scenario is as follows:
One thread is a producer, and the other thread is a consumer.
To access critical sections, I have been using the method of disabling interrupts for thread synchronization.
During the development process, I found that disabling interrupts does not meet the performance requirements for high real-time applications. The thread synchronization in my code involves at most communication between two threads.
My questions are:
1.In this scenario, is it still necessary to use thread synchronization mechanisms (e.g., disabling interrupts, semaphores, mutexes)?
2.If not using disabling interrupts, is there a better method that can meet real-time requirements without causing data contention?
Thank you very much for your guidance and suggestions!

We are talking single-core mcu, right? Is OS truly cooperative? If the ONLY way to switch threads is via explicit yield (no preemption at all), and ONLY the threads are accessing some shared data (i.e. interrupt handlers don't) then it is not necessary to synchronize THAT data, because everything between yields happens essentially inside a giant critical section wrt to the data. Secondly, if disabling interrupts to access shared data breaks your performance needs, you are doing it wrong. No-interrupt area should be limited to a few instructions. Thirdly, there's ol' good ldrex/strex.

Yes, mine is a single core MCU, and mine is a cooperative scheduler.

All we know about your case is "One thread is a producer, and the other thread is a consumer." From that information it is impossible to deduce whether you need synchronization and of what kind.

You do not need to disable interrupts if you do not change anything which is shared. That is the correct way.
